# User-defined field's value not saving into the database

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created an approval process and part of the code consists of getting the approver's email (who is in the company tree (screen id: EP204061)).

Snippet of the code which retrieves the approver's email is as follows:

```
Contact contact = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<EPCompanyTreeMember.contactID>>>>.Select(Base, ePCompanyTreeMember.ContactID);
BAccountExt3 bAccountExt3 = row.GetExtension<BAccountExt3>();

if (ePCompanyTreeMember == null)
{
    bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail = "";
    cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt3.usrApproverEmail>(row, bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail);
}

if (ePCompanyTreeMember != null)
{
    bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail = contact.EMail;
    cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt3.usrApproverEmail>(row, bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail);
}
```

The values are retrieved correctly but are not being saved into the database.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `ePCompanyTreeMember` variable being set?

Should your if statement reference contact instead (as shown below)?

```
Contact contact = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<EPCompanyTreeMember.contactID>>>>.Select(Base, ePCompanyTreeMember.ContactID);
BAccountExt3 bAccountExt3 = row.GetExtension<BAccountExt3>();

if (contact == null)
{
    bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail = "";
    cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt3.usrApproverEmail>(row, bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail);
}
else
{
    bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail = contact.EMail;
    cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt3.usrApproverEmail>(row, bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail);
}
```

For what it's worth, you could shorten the code by using optional chaining and null coalescing as shown below:

```
Contact contact = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<EPCompanyTreeMember.contactID>>>>.Select(Base, ePCompanyTreeMember.ContactID);
BAccountExt3 bAccountExt3 = row.GetExtension<BAccountExt3>();
// contact? effectively says if contact is null, then use null rather than trying .EMail on a null variable
// ?? says if the value on the left side of ?? is null, then use the value on the right side (empty string)
bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail = contact?.EMail ?? "";
cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt3.usrApproverEmail>(row, bAccountExt3.UsrApproverEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this code within the companytree maint screen or does your Code/BLC contain the EPCompanyTree as a view? Not sure how you are populating the above code. IF the screen running it doesn't contain a reference to ContactID then this will never be populated.

Example from the Business Account screen or Customer screen the BAccount.ContactID is accessible because it is contained within the cache from the Current record being displayed.

More information on how and where you are implementing this could help us provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this code misses the Cache.Update command
SetValueExt does only 2 things:

1. calls property setter
2. invokes FieldVerifying and FieldUpdated event handlers.
   but it does not change the cache status to Updated and therefore does not persist change

You can only skip this update if this code is from the _RowUpdated handler of this BAccount cache (so that it is already marked as updated)